How does the Arnoldi iterations algorithm deal with repeated eigenvalues?
The simplest possible matrix I can think of to use an arnoldi method is the identity matrix.
In this case the Krylov sequence is just $\{v, v, v, v, \cdots\}$ for any $v$.
Thus the span of the krylov space is just a single vector. However, the space of eigenvectors of $I$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$. I have read multiple resources on the topic, and I just don't understand how the method would sucessfully generate an orthonormal basis that spans the full space of eigenvalues of the identity matrix.

In the case of a hermitian matrix $A$, Arnoldi iterations are usually implemented through the Lanczos algorithm.Rhoughly, the idea is to iteratively create a basis of orthogonal vectors by taking the last added vector $\vec{v}$, multiplying it by your matrix $A$, and substracting the components that are parallel to the previous basis.
Now, this works only if the new vector is non-zero, otherwise it can't be part of a basis! In particular, if $\vec{v}$ was an eigenvector of $A$, then the next vector gets a contribution $A\vec{v}$ (and another term coming from the vector preceding $\vec{v}$). The orthogonalization leaves the null vector, which is not a proper candidate to complete a basis. In this situation, the Lanczos algorithm chooses an arbitrary non-zero vector which is orthogonal to the current incomplete basis.
The takeaway is that these exceptions are properly dealt with by arbitrarily choosing new vectors to span the full eigenstates, one by one. In particular, this happens at each step of the algorithm in your example where $A$ is the identity matrix.

I see, is there a particularly good mechanism to pick the arbitrary vector?

As it often happens, however, the difficult case is not when a quantity in your algorithm is zero, but when it's $10^{-15}$.

@Makogan I think any strategy is good in general: since the vector will be orthonormalized, in any way we end up with a vector with magnitude 1 and perfectly orthogonal to the resulting basis. However it could surely be optimized in some cases if we have some spectral information to identify subspaces of interest in the Hilbert space, and find at first a basis for those.
